# gradle task inputs are polluted

Tags: gwt, gradle

I'm trying to create a task to build gwt modules. The compilation does work, but i have the problem with task inputs/ouputs. The task is being executed even when it shouldn't be, like when i change files outside the input folders.
I created a task to get the information about tasks' inputs/outputs, and it showed that there are some 'implicit' inputs that affects on the task up-to-dateness. (like `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`)

here are the gists of my build.gradle and `taskInfo` task output

https://gist.github.com/demoth/7007823

the task i'm concerned about is `gwtshared` and `gwtgwtgradle` (line 63 and 80 in the second file).

Somehow i need to remove the `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` inputs.

Comment: so far, investigating this i found that the undesired inputs come from `classpath resPath`, `classpath javaPath` and `classpath configurations.runtime` statements (line 36-38 in build.gradle). Looks like all the files from classpath  go straight to the task inputs. I cannot remove it because gwt comiler won't find all the required sources. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want the `JavaExec` task to be `UP-TO-DATE` despite its class path having changed?

Comment: Yes, it's the way the gwtcompiler works. Of cource i'd like to feed the gwtcompiler only with sources that should be compiled with gwt, like change lines 36-37 to
`classpath resPath + '/' + modulePath + '/Shared.gwt.xml'`
`classpath javaPath + '/' + modulePath + '/shared/Greeting.java'` .
I provided the resulted command (command.input in gist) that showed overall classpath, but gwtcompilers doesn't work with this classpath, `[ERROR] Unable to find 'org/shared/Shared.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?`

Comment: so i have to provide classpath with all the sources

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser GWT loads resources from its classpath, but only looks at a subset of it, and @demoth would like the task to be UP-TO-DATE when changes are outside that subset. Though @demoth, you could have generators and linkers that look outside the source-path, so it's not that simple. I really do believe you should use distinct source directories; but you could possibly copy files from the source-path into an intermediary folder (using a `Copy` task with an `include` filter) and use that in the classpath, if the `Copy` task is UP-TO-DATE, then the GWT Compiler task should too.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer that's a good suggestion! i'll try to use temporary folders and write here if i get any results

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser @demoth BTW, I do believe this is what Gradle should do by default, along with passing that temporary folder(s) as a `-sourcepath` to javac; otherwise it could compile despite broken _sourceSets_ _excludes_ (e.g. you exclude `foo.java` but `Bar.java` references it, and unless you copy/symlink source files **and** use `-sourcepath`, javac would find `Foo.java` and compile it silently). This is what [Buck](http://facebook.github.io/buck/) does FWIW.